# Omniauth-facebook login does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth, omniauth-facebook

I cloned [example facebook integration](https://github.com/AnnieLee/blog-facebook)

this repo to see how the omniauth-facebook works. I setup my own app_id and app_secret from my facebook app.

The problem is the facebook login doesn't works. 
It throws an error: ***"Insecure Login Blocked: You can't get an access token or log in to this app from an insecure page. Try re-loading the page as https://"*** when I try login via facebook.

Does anyone  have error like this one? How to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Facebook enforces HTTPS by default, but you can turn it off if you need to:
You can read more about it [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/security#checklist)

[This is how I turn it off for my learning project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8j5VF.png)

Comment: Thank you, I also need add valid redirects and now works.

Comment: I tried to turn it off but it cant be turned off. I think they had some policy changes recently.

Comment: @Daniel can u please provide the valid redirects? Since the facebook update my "example.com/" is not working anymore.

Comment: @Bolic Since Facebook blocked "Use strict mode fore Redirects..." you should add all valid redirect uris. It could look like thishttps://ibb.co/nsLehx 
Add also app domains in settings. I hope it will help you.