# Facebook New Strict App Settings not working for fboauth

Tags: facebook, http, https

Summary of the problem:
the "Enforce HTTPS for OAuth Redirects and SDK APIs" option in Facebook Login Settings, which cannot be disabled.

According to the Facebook help (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/security): This setting requires HTTPS for OAuth Redirects and pages getting access tokens with the JavaScript SDK. All new apps created as of March 2018 have this setting on by default and you should plan to migrate any existing apps to use only HTTPS URLs by March 2019.

The fboauth default url for authentication in R is http://localhost:1410/ NOT an https:// address. I can't even save it as a valid Oauth redirect it would seem.

I've tried everything and I am using Facebook's R package. Basically following this string of posts, and the local server option that they suggest is not working:

https://github.com/pablobarbera/Rfacebook/issues/170

**is there a way I can redefine the fboauth function to get it to generate an https:// url?**

Comment: Fact is simply, you will need HTTPS. The github issue you linked to refers to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49353496/ as a possible approach. If anything is “not working” about that, you’ll have to be a little more specific.

Answer (score 0):

First up, have you been using rFacebook package in the last couple of months?
If not this may be a solution:
After the API change in late January, Pablo did make adjustments to compensate.
What you need to do is download the dev version of the package direct from github by:

```
devtools::install_github('pablobarbera/Rfacebook')
```

After that the existing code should be fine. 
Since January, we no longer have access to User ID' or Usernames which is a really unfortunate loss.

If you need anything more, drop me a pm

Comment: Hi Robert FC, thank you for replying! I can't figure out how to pm you on stack, so I'll just ask my Q here. Once I've installed Mr.Barbera's package into R, how do I override the Rfacebook package I have already installed from CRAN (not Mr. Barbera's edited version)?

Comment: This is how I installed the package: install_github("pablobarbera/Rfacebook/Rfacebook") I tried to run the same command, fboauth <- fbOAuth(appid,appsecret)  after generating a new appid and appsecret and saving them as variables, and I am still getting the same error "Warning
Can't Load URL: " etc like in the github thread

Answer (score 0):

Do you still follow the format:

```
library("Rfacebook")

appid <- "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
appsecret <- "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"

fboauth <- fbOAuth(appid, appsecret)
```

Make sure you are logged into the FB account linked to the 'appid' and 'appsecret'?

Comment: yes I did, I ended up just generating a temporary token that lasts for 2 hours just to get the data I needed.